# Efficient way to clean a csv?

Tags: pandas

I am parsing and modifying large files (about a gig per month) which contain a record of every interaction. These files are sent to me by our client, so I am stuck with what they contain. I am using pandas to clean them up a bit, add some information, etc.

I keep running into issues where, out of 1 million+ rows, 1 to 10 values in the datetime column are not a date. A value meant for another column is in the date column due to some issue with comma separation (this is from the client's query, not mine) so it might say the word 'Closed' or something.

How do I drop these rows? I can see the ones with errors when I use df.sort('Datetime'). I just want a way to drop these quickly.

Here are my ideas:

1. There is a column called 'TransID' which ALWAYS begins with the
   letter 'H' (and it always is 9 digits) UNLESS there is an error when another column value has shifted into this column
2. The date column should always have a value (notnull)

Can someone help think of a way to solve this problem? (I think this date thing is the key issue because I have formulas which subtract StartDate from EndDate.. if one of those contains a word then it messes up the entire process. Maybe I can create some error exception or drop error rows?)

Answer (score 0):

Use the H column to filter out the error rows using a boolean index and the [vectorized string methods.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods)

```
good_rows_mask = df.TransID.str[0] == 'H'
df = df[good_rows_mask]
```

Comment: Cool - thank you. 

Can I drop specific rows based on the default index (like 362739, 781146). The good_rows covers most errors, but I see a couple which are definitely wrong even though the 'TransID' column is correct.These columns are concatenated with / symbols. Can I say that certain columns should not include a '/

For the date columns I added coerce = True.

Comment: good_ctv = ((~rep['CT'].str.contains('/')) & (rep['Case_ID'].str[0] == 'H'))

I tried this and it seems to be working great. thanks